# Adding COPPA compliance for push notifications in android app

Tags: android

We have a requirement to have our app compliance with COPPA in order to send push notifications for the children. I am really clueless on how to proceed further, I searched for third party libraries for integrating this thing into my app, but I didn't found anything yet. Can someone suggest me a good idea on how to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

If you require COPPA compliance, you'll need verified parent consent. It's not easy because the FTC requirements conflict with Apple's guidelines. For instance, you can gain verified parent consent through a completed credit card financial transaction - but the iTunes in-app purchases do not qualify. A credit card transaction would be so easy but Apple will reject apps that don't use in-app purchases for digital services.

Here is the FAQ provided by the FTC that clarifies all of these questions:
http://www.business.ftc.gov/documents/0493-Complying-with-COPPA-Frequently-Asked-Questions

And the main COPPA page has more helpful information.
http://www.business.ftc.gov/privacy-and-security/childrens-privacy

We're currently trying to find a way through this. Since this question is a year old, I'm wondering if you found a solution?