# If I use Google Analytics & Firebase services(e.g FCM, Firebase Analytics) in Designed for Families Apps will violates COPPA policy?

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, google-play

I got a Notification from Google Play that is app publishing is rejected due to terms violation.

But in play console i declared the my app is primarily child directed.

**Note:** Am not using any Ads SDK (it's Ads Free App)

[image]

My Apps Uses Push Notification for Re engagement &  Google Analytics for user behavior analysis.

My doubt is will the use of Google Analytics & Firebase services(e.g FCM, Firebase Analytics) in Designed for Families Apps will violates COPPA policy? if yes how can i analysis the user behavior?

referenced url

[Android - app has been rejected because it is primarily child-directed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45519124/android-app-has-been-rejected-because-it-is-primarily-child-directed)

[Google play policy update - privacy vs Google Analytics, Firebase Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45492627/google-play-policy-update-privacy-vs-google-analytics-firebase-analytics)

[Adding COPPA compliance for push notifications in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206238/adding-coppa-compliance-for-push-notifications-in-android-app)

Comment: [Here is what Firebase automatically collects](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317486).  None of which is personally identifiable.  As long as you aren't allowing the user to login to Facebook and collecting name, age, sex, location, etc.. you should be fine as far as analytics are concerned.

Comment: Push notifications are interesting because from my perspective, you can send notifications to a specific device without knowing who exactly uses that device.  If this is a problem (which I don't think it is) then you can schedule local notifications for re-enagagement and cancel them whenever the app is opened).